# Можно рисовать самим картинки в paint и добавлять в html код?

Tags: html

Можно рисовать самим картинки в paint и добавлять в html код?

Comment: злободневный вопрос))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно можно, есть очень хорошая версия программы Paint, для быстрой наброски изображений самое то! Вот ссылка на официальный сайт: [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/redirect/main_hm.html). А в html изображения добавлять так `<img src="путь_к_папке/image.png">`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно.
Нарисуй картинку в Paint, сохрани.
Загрузи её (на сервер).
В нужное место html кода вставь `<img src="путь к картинке" alt="Описание(по желанию)" title="Подсказка(по желанию)" />` . 
Так же можно через css, но это чуть сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

Можно! Рисуй Paint  и вставляй с помощью тега `<img>` ))